# Why MongoDB query is slow while using index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is index in MongoDB:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "project_id" : 1,
        "parse_date" : 1
    },
    "name" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1",
    "ns" : "test.offer",
    "partialFilterExpression" : {
        "active" : false,
        "errors" : {
            "$exists" : true
        }
    },
    "background" : true
}
```

But the query which uses this index is running very slow for no reason:

```
> db.currentOp()
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "desc" : "conn16685",
            "threadId" : "119533779793664",
            "connectionId" : 16685,
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:49154",
            "active" : true,
            "opid" : 100695187,
            "secs_running" : 60,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(60950200),
            "op" : "command",
            "ns" : "test.offer",
            "query" : {
                "count" : "offer",
                "query" : {
                    "project_id" : ObjectId("5818acae439a6b1e588b4568"),
                    "parse_date" : ISODate("2017-01-20T08:21:51.876Z"),
                    "active" : false,
                    "errors" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                }
            },
            "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { project_id: 1.0, parse_date: 1.0 }",
            "numYields" : 2422,
            "locks" : {
                "Global" : "r",
                "Database" : "r",
                "Collection" : "r"
            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "lockStats" : {
                "Global" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(4846)
                    }
                },
                "Database" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(2423)
                    }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                    "acquireCount" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(2423)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "desc" : "conn17711",
            "threadId" : "119533772400384",
            "connectionId" : 17711,
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:45980",
            "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
            "active" : true,
            "opid" : 100827280,
            "secs_running" : 0,
            "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(73),
            "op" : "command",
            "ns" : "admin.$cmd",
            "query" : {
                "currentOp" : 1
            },
            "numYields" : 0,
            "locks" : {

            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "lockStats" : {

            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Explain

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.offer",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "active" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "parse_date" : {
                        "$eq" : ISODate("2017-01-20T08:21:51.876Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "project_id" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("5818acae439a6b1e588b4568")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "errors" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "active" : {
                            "$eq" : false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "errors" : {
                            "$exists" : true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "project_id" : 1,
                    "parse_date" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "project_id" : [ ],
                    "parse_date" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : true,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "project_id" : [
                        "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                    ],
                    "parse_date" : [
                        "[new Date(1484900511876), new Date(1484900511876)]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "errors" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "project_id" : 1,
                        "parse_date" : 1,
                        "active" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1_active_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "project_id" : [ ],
                        "parse_date" : [ ],
                        "active" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "project_id" : [
                            "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                        ],
                        "parse_date" : [
                            "[new Date(1484900511876), new Date(1484900511876)]"
                        ],
                        "active" : [
                            "[false, false]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "parse_date" : {
                                "$eq" : ISODate("2017-01-20T08:21:51.876Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "errors" : {
                                "$exists" : true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "project_id" : 1,
                        "active" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "project_id_1_active_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "project_id" : [ ],
                        "active" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : true,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "project_id" : [
                            "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                        ],
                        "active" : [
                            "[false, false]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 8084,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 21352,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 8084,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 8084,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "active" : {
                            "$eq" : false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "errors" : {
                            "$exists" : true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 8084,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 21333,
            "works" : 8085,
            "advanced" : 8084,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 998,
            "restoreState" : 998,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 8084,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 8084,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 120,
                "works" : 8085,
                "advanced" : 8084,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 998,
                "restoreState" : 998,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "project_id" : 1,
                    "parse_date" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "project_id" : [ ],
                    "parse_date" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : true,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "project_id" : [
                        "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                    ],
                    "parse_date" : [
                        "[new Date(1484900511876), new Date(1484900511876)]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 8084,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [
            {
                "nReturned" : 99,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "errors" : {
                            "$exists" : true
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 99,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 99,
                    "needTime" : 2,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 6,
                    "restoreState" : 6,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 6,
                        "restoreState" : 6,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "project_id" : 1,
                            "parse_date" : 1,
                            "active" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1_active_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "project_id" : [ ],
                            "parse_date" : [ ],
                            "active" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "project_id" : [
                                "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                            ],
                            "parse_date" : [
                                "[new Date(1484900511876), new Date(1484900511876)]"
                            ],
                            "active" : [
                                "[false, false]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 3,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "parse_date" : {
                                    "$eq" : ISODate("2017-01-20T08:21:51.876Z")
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "errors" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 3,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 3,
                    "needTime" : 98,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 6,
                    "restoreState" : 6,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 6,
                        "restoreState" : 6,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "project_id" : 1,
                            "active" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "project_id_1_active_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "project_id" : [ ],
                            "active" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : true,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "project_id" : [
                                "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                            ],
                            "active" : [
                                "[false, false]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nReturned" : 101,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 101,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 101,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "active" : {
                                    "$eq" : false
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "errors" : {
                                    "$exists" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 101,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 101,
                    "advanced" : 101,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 6,
                    "restoreState" : 6,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 101,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 101,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 101,
                        "advanced" : 101,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 6,
                        "restoreState" : 6,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "project_id" : 1,
                            "parse_date" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "project_id_1_parse_date_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "project_id" : [ ],
                            "parse_date" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : true,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "project_id" : [
                                "[ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568'), ObjectId('5818acae439a6b1e588b4568')]"
                            ],
                            "parse_date" : [
                                "[new Date(1484900511876), new Date(1484900511876)]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 101,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "...",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.4.1",
        "gitVersion" : "5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see there are no other queries that can lock database or collection.

What can cause such behavior?

Comment: There is just too many matching docs in the index? Because after index scan, it has to go read actual documents, to filter by `active` and `errors` fields.

Comment: This is a partial index, it doesn't contain any documents that require reading.

Comment: Right, missed the partial part.

Comment: Can you include the output of `explain(true)` for this query? What specific version of MongoDB server is this and what storage engine are you using?

Comment: Added explain(true) results to question.